# RadSpreadsheet - Give columns a unique identifier

Tags: c#, telerik, spreadsheet

I've some issues giving the columns a unique identifier using Teleriks RadSpreadsheet (Workbook, Worksheet etc).

Here is my problem: My first row is a header row, e.g.:

| Name (father) | Age | Name (mother) | ....

Those column headers in my first row aren't unique. They have been named exactly the same, although they are used for different things. To improve extendibility, I dont want to use indexes to find the specified column I am looking for. When I add another column inbetween, the program should still work fine without any adjustments.

Instead, my program should use a normal key to find the column. For example: My program gets an request to return the column, in which

What I've tried:
- Hidden columns are not available in the version I currently use.
- Finding the columns by an easy string search isnt working either, cause they arent unique, so if I search for the father name column, I have two columns with the header "name" and cannot differentiate, what exactly is the right column.

```
for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
{ 
      //Check value equals searchtxt.. 
}
```

- I wasnt been able (havent found anything) to give the cells / columns a hidden name, like 'mother name' and 'father name')

Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data structure like Dictionary for example where you can define a key - which will be the "hidden name", and a value - the CellIndex of the header cell.

To keep the dictionary up-to-date you will have to subscribe to some events like

```
Worksheet.Cells.CellRangeInsertedOrRemoved
```

and update the cached names to match their eventually new CellIndex. This way you will use the dictionary to find the cell index corresponding to the name defined by you.